Help Identifying Connection Type for YIHUA TFT 10-pin Display (1.75 inch, FPC Connector)
I’m trying to repurpose a batch of small TFT screens salvaged from disposable vapes (1.8-inch, made by YIHUA TFT). I’ve searched for information on the display and the connector type but haven’t found much, so I’m hoping to get some guidance.
The screen has a 10-pin FPC cable, 6.4 mm wide, and it connects using a press-in/snap-in connector, not the usual ZIF slide-in type. The ribbon cable reads YIHUA TFT YH-177RX6955C2. I’m attaching pictures of the display and the board it was connected to, including a close-up of the chip labeled “Notion,” which seems to be the display controller.
I found this blog about something similar . This website looks to be similar to what I'm trying to do. Just a different screen/connector. Mine might not be as difficult as this I think (possibly even more difficult)? But I could be wrong. Either way I believe I am on the right track.
What I’ve Tried:
Searches for YIHUA TFT and YH-177RX6955C2 didn’t yield any specific datasheets or specs.
I looked into ZIF and FFC connectors, but this one seems different (more like a direct press-fit type).
I plan to interface it with an Arduino or ESP32, assuming it might use a standard protocol like SPI, but I’m unsure where to start without a pinout.
Questions:
Can anyone help confirm the type of FPC connector this is?
Does anyone have experience with YIHUA TFT displays or similar press-fit connectors?
Are there recommended steps for testing unknown TFT displays with a microcontroller?








Welcome to SE/RE! You took the [tour], which is good and rare, thank you. Please do not add new information in comments, this is not a forum. Please [edit] your question to enhance it. -- What does your research on the assumed MCU reveal? And you could re-engineer the connections of the connector's pins to find supply lines and communicatoin lines. Then can happen with partial disassembly, as you have multiple of the devices.
